# PostgreSQL JDBC exception: "No results were returned by the query" when executing transaction with results

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm attempting to run a transaction block that updates the selected rows for processing, then returns the rows for the ResultSet. However, despite results existing, Postgres JDBC doesn't seem to recognize that the transaction block produced results, and subsequently throws an exception.

Transaction block:

```
begin transaction;
WITH queue AS (
  UPDATE validation_queue vq
    SET status = 'processing', validation_request_date = current_timestamp
    WHERE vq.id IN (
      SELECT id
      FROM validation_queue
      WHERE status = 'pending'
        AND vendor = 'vendor1'
    ) returning id
)
SELECT email_address, account_id, lead_tracking_id, id, file_validation_id FROM validation_queue WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM queue);
commit;
```

Exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:104)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at io.mailthru.quartzjobs.EmailValidationEmailOversightJob.execute(EmailValidationEmailOversightJob.java:79)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

Code snippet

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try (Connection con = new ConnectionManager().getConnection()) {

            ps = con.prepareStatement(SQL_QUERY);

            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) { ... }
            ...
         } catch (SQLException ex) { ... }
}
```

Running the query in my IDE gives me the subsequent records successfully.

Comment: Remove the `begin transaction` and `commit` from your query string.

Comment: You shouldn't include transaction management statements like `begin transaction` and `commit` when using JDBC. You should manage transactions through the JDBC API.